# Change active link color

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Problem

I have an issue with my website, I want to change the color of the selected link to blue, and if other is selected put it back to gray, but don`t know how to target the **clicked link** in javascript. Here is my code.

```js
var center = document.getElementsByClassName("center");
for (let i = 0; i < center.length; i++) {
    center[i].addEventListener("click", DivSelector());
}
function DivSelector() {
    for (let i = 0; i < center.length; i++) {
        center[i].classList.Remove('active');
    };    
}
```

```css
.nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #505b67;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.active {
  color: #4460f1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tab-ul">
    <li id="Profile">
        <a class="center nav-item" href="">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li id="Change-Password">
        <a class="center nav-item" href="">Change password</a>
    </li>
    <li id="Notifications">
        <a class="center nav-item" href="">Notifications</a>
    </li>
    <li id="My-Cards">
        <a class="center nav-item" href="">My Cards</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Don`t know how to select the clicked link here for adding the 'active' class.

Comment: Michael Horn said this in his answer, but I want to put it in a different way... when you use `DivSelector()` you are _calling_ the function, when you use `DivSelector` without the parentheses you are _referring to_ the function. So `.addEventListener("click", DivSelector());` means _call_ DivSelector and use its return value as the 2nd parameter to addEventListener. `.addEventListener("click", DivSelector);` means pass _a reference_ to the DivSelector function, this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much very much for the explanation, didn't understand it till know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. its working

```
  var center = document.getElementsByClassName("center");
  for (let i = 0; i < center.length; i++) {
    center[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
      for (let i = 0; i < center.length; i++) {
         center[i].classList.remove('active');
         e.target.classList.add('active');
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: tried too, still not working, there must be some other code in my project breaking it

Comment: your anchor href should be `<a href="#">` or `<a href="javascript:;">`

Comment: replace your javascript with mine. your `classList.Remove()` wrong. it shold be `classList.remove()`

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you for this, been trying to fix this for hours, the problem was the # on the hrefs, mine were empty, its working know

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the class active to the actual link of the page you are on. So when you on the profile page you add active to profile link and none of the others

**PROFILE PAGE**

```
<ul class="nav-tab-ul">
            <li id="Profile">
              <a class="center nav-item active" href="">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li id="Change-Password">
              <a class="center nav-item" href="">Change password</a>
            </li>
            <li id="Notifications">
              <a class="center nav-item" href="">Notifications</a>
            </li>
            <li id="My-Cards">
              <a class="center nav-item" href="">My Cards</a>
            </li>
  </ul>
```

**CHANGE PASSWORD PAGE**

When you on the change password page you add the active class to that link and none of the others.

```
<ul class="nav-tab-ul">
                <li id="Profile">
                  <a class="center nav-item" href="">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li id="Change-Password">
                  <a class="center nav-item active" href="">Change password</a>
                </li>
                <li id="Notifications">
                  <a class="center nav-item" href="">Notifications</a>
                </li>
                <li id="My-Cards">
                  <a class="center nav-item" href="">My Cards</a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

If these are separate pages there is no need for JS?

If you are using one header file and including the file into all your pages then it will be a different solution. Let us know why you want to use JS

Comment: i need to use js because i need the active class to be added dynamically every time user touches a link

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. When adding your event listener, you called DivSelector, meaning you added the return value of DivSelector() as a listener, which is void. Instead just pass the name of the function you want to add as a listener.
2. You need to add the 'active' class to the clicked element after removing it from all the others. You can get the clicked element by using the `event` argument passed to your event listener. The element will be `event.target`.
3. DivSelector should be defined before it's used, so it should be moved above the rest of the code.

Here's an example:

```js
function DivSelector(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < center.length; i++) {
    center[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  event.target.classList.add('active');
}

let center = document.querySelectorAll("center");

for (let i = 0; i < center.length; i++) {
  center[i].addEventListener("click", DivSelector);
}
```

```css
.nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #505b67;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.active {
  color: #4460f1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tab-ul">
  <li id="Profile">
    <a class="center nav-item" href="#">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li id="Change-Password">
    <a class="center nav-item" href="#">Change password</a>
  </li>
  <li id="Notifications">
    <a class="center nav-item" href="#">Notifications</a>
  </li>
  <li id="My-Cards">
    <a class="center nav-item" href="#">My Cards</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but just copied and pasted it all and its still not working

Comment: Strange, it works running the code in the browser here. Are you getting any errors in the console that may provide a hint?

Comment: Yes that's what confuses me, it works here, not having any log errors

Comment: Works in the snippet for me also. Couple of tips, Michael... use `let center` not `var`, and if you `let center = document.querySelectorAll('.center');` you get a `NodeList` instead of `.getElementsByClassName(...)` which gives a `HTMLCollection` — "and?" you say... with a NodeList you can then use modern constructs like `center.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'))` instead of a for-loop with a loop counter, which you can't do with an HTMLCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Stephen - I normally write my own code in the manner you've suggested, but I must admit I copied the OP's code without giving much attention to those details. Always better to point out these best practices though, so it's much appreciated

Comment: its working now, vlknu21 just found the bug, my hrefs were empty

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for your help, gave you upvotes, but I`m new here, so mine don't count

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element clicked in `event.currentTarget`.

```js
const nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("center");
for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].addEventListener("click", divSelector);
}

function divSelector(event) {
    removeAllActives();
  event.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}

function removeAllActives() {
    const actives = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  for (let i = 0; i < actives.length; i++) {
    actives[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="center"> Link 1 </a> <br/>
<a class="center"> Link 2 </a>
```